# How to align a single Menu Item in a NavigationMenu?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to set set the "User" menu item to left align, but could not find the correct method. Below is my code snippet

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server"  EnableViewState="false" 

<asp:MenuItem Text="User" ToolTip="User"> 

                               <asp:MenuItem Text="Profile" ToolTip="Profile" />
                               <asp:MenuItem Text="Settings" ToolTip="Settings" />
                               <asp:MenuItem Text="Sign Out" ToolTip="Sign Out" />
                           </asp:MenuItem>
          </Items>`
  </asp:Menu>
```